# Print lines after one grep pattern until a new pattern is found

Tags: sed, grep

I want to get all lines of a textfile following a certain grep match until I hit another, different grep match. But if there is another match after that, I want to show lines again.
Example: My textfile looks similar to:

```
Pattern_A
line1
line2
Pattern_B
line3
line4
Pattern_A
line5
line6
Pattern_B
line7
```

Now I need a command, that outputs:

```
Pattern_A
line1
line2
Pattern_A
line5
line6
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sure this must be a duplicate but I can't find it - `awk '/Pattern_A/ {p=1} /Pattern_B/ {p=0} p' file`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does this also allow RegEx, like the wildcard *  ?

Comment: Yes, you can put any supported regex between `/` and `/` - note that different awk implementations may support more or fewer extended regex features. Also not that `*` on its own is a quantifier not a wildcard in regex (don't confuse regular expressions with shell globs).

Comment: see also this cross site duplicate with various cases: [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/)

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz 'Pattern_A(\n.*?)+(?=Pattern_B\n)' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/Pattern_A/,/Pattern_B/{/Pattern_B/d;p}' file
```

Output:

```
Pattern_A
line1
line2
Pattern_A
line5
line6
```